# Why does Haskell's interactive REPL in Emacs kill itself when compilation fails?

Tags: haskell, emacs

I was having trouble understanding what was going on in my Haskell interactive mode. I would load in the file with `C-c C-l` and that would start the interactive process, but when I reload again and there is a syntax error or something, I can no longer print anything into the REPL, it is read-only. I looked around for why this was happening and I couldn't find any sources who seem to have similar problems... However, I did look in the `*haskell-process-log*` and found that Powershell was being called, and the program was exiting in the following line of code:

```
-> :!powershell -Command "& { cd c:/Users/Michael/Functional/PS12/ ; hasktags -e -x (ls -fi *.hs -exclude \"#*#\" -name -r) ; exit }"
```

I have no idea why this is being called or from where, something to do with hasktags. Is there a way I could shut this off?